Complex lon/lat format manipulation
I originally developed a model to work with a df as df1_ref. Now, I found more data I need in a different format as df2.
df1_ref:
   id   country         point_id    lon         lat         value_A
10195   United States   0       -98.52838821    35.33514183 22
10195   United States   1       -98.52838821    35.33514183 22
10195   United States   2       -98.52838821    35.33514183 22
10195   United States   3       -98.6100762     35.34134382 22
  557   United States   0       -98.6100762     35.34134382 33
  557   United States   1       -98.68102873    35.32256443 33
  557   United States   2       -98.68102873    35.32256443 33
11354   United States   0       -95.4872305     31.85227725 22
11354   United States   1       -95.4872305     31.85227725 22
11354   United States   2       -95.474907      31.90126317 22
10131   United States   0       -98.7424264     35.777792   25
10131   United States   1       -98.58307728    35.74085314 25
10131   United States   2       -98.58307728    35.74085314 25


df2:
id                              country             point_id_0                     mid_points                                                    last_point_n                               route_id    value_B
[10195, 557, 10123, 10105]      United States         [35.31514548, -98.46788543]     [[35.33514183, -98.52838821], [35.34134382, -98.6100762]]    [35.50457366645043, -98.98023683317503]  883       3500.69
[10029, 10027, 11354, 11355]      United States       [31.77540736, -95.11453227]     [[31.83779617, -95.1591275], [31.89157317, -95.20337925]]    [31.3187429993161, -95.450949000766]     1156        105.9092
[10131, 10204, 553, 2855]         United States       [35.77292283, -98.69682372]     [[35.777792, -98.7424264], [35.74085314, -98.58307728]]      [35.7434880000976, -99.2341759999093]      1186      4478.04


dput(df2[1:3,])
structure(list(id = c("[10195, 557, 10123, 10105, 10088, 10083]", 
"[5349, 5369, 5414, 5455]", "[13184, 13217, 13235, 13251]"), 
    country = c("United States", "United States", "United States"
    ), point_id_0 = c("[35.31514548, -98.46788543]", "[40.7595028, -80.78622874]", 
    "[26.8019707, -99.18425714]"), mid_points = c("[[35.33514183, -98.52838821], [35.34134382, -98.6100762], [35.32256443, -98.68102873], [35.314511, -98.74060343], [35.298251, -98.796368], [35.30914456, -98.87914044], [35.40467971, -98.97597341], [35.50457367, -98.98023683]]", 
    "[[40.803904, -80.757632], [40.835328, -80.761536], [40.832602, -80.728872], [40.824192, -80.628096], [40.844928, -80.588928], [40.870912, -80.51968], [40.887313, -80.441874], [40.911872, -80.325376], [40.935712, -80.146112]]", 
    "[[26.77083569, -99.16190154], [26.8606385, -99.0916255], [26.99262, -99.04733833], [27.04302367, -99.0116915], [27.24608845, -98.94356648]]"
    ), last_point_n = c("[35.50457366645043, -98.98023683317503]", 
    "[40.9265919994913, -79.9925760003392]", "[27.24608845465542, -98.94356647741596]"
    ), route_id = c(883, 884, 885), value_B = c(3500.69, 20911.7359999998, 
    1794.77)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

I need to convert df2 into df1_ref for me to run my previous model.
Here I explain what I need:
Various id in df2 come in the same observation, e.g., [10195, 557, 10123, 10105...]; I simplify to 4 id's for the example. So, I need to split it into rows. I share some examples as how it would look like in df1.
point_id_0 from df2 is lat and lon of point_id = 0 of df1. So, I need to split point_id_0 in lat and lon columns, respectively.
mid_points from df2 are the next coordinates lat/lot of my network, each pair of coordinates belongs to one id in the same order (1,2,3...). So, first mid_points of route_id is id = 557, then to become 1 in point_id.
last_point_n is the last coordinate, belonging to the last id, e.g., 10105;  point_id = 3.
Therefore, df3 is built from df2, considering df1 as a reference. So, the final df3 is as df1 + value_B + route_id.
I have tried the following and it works:
df3 <- cbind(df2,
             do.call(rbind,
                     lapply(df2$point_id_0, jsonlite::fromJSON))) 

However, it did not work for mid_points as it would require first to convert all [lat, lon] into rows and then split it in columns.

I lack the time to formulate full answer, but take a look at separate_longer_delim() from tidyr package. This should solve your case. And consider to do the transformation of df2 in more than one step.

Could you please edit your question and include a reproducible sample from your actual df2 so we'd have a clear understanding of the structure you are working with and have something to test with? Ouput from dput(df2[1:3,]) would be ideal.

I have added dput(df2[1:3,]) as suggested by @margusl

Focusing just on the 1st row of dput variant of your df2, there are 6 id values ([10195, 557, 10123, 10105, 10088, 10083]), but 8 mid_points + 2 additional points (point_id_0, last_point_n ), what's the expected resulting row count for just that single input row? 60 as in 6 * (8+2)? Or it should be somehow 6? In your first df2 example number of ids conveniently aligns with the number of coordinate pairs for every row, (4 id values & 2+1+1 coordinates),  in dput sample this does not apply anymore. Is the original data source JSON / GeoJSON?

Yes, I just found that the [[lat, lon], [lat, lon], etc] is a JSON format. So, I applied this for point_id_0 (which has only one pair of lat, lon) and it works: df3 <- cbind(df2, do.call(rbind, lapply(df2$point_id_0, jsonlite::fromJSON))) . However, it did not work for mid_points as it would require first to convert all [lat, lon] into rows and then split it in columns.

@dmoyaec, please try to find an answer to the first part of my pervious comment -- what is the expected result for cases where number of ids does not match with the total number of coordinates. For all 3 rows of your dput sample you have less  ids, than mid_points , (6, 4, 4)  vs  (8, 9, 5), https://i.sstatic.net/yR65ms0w.png

@margusl, I have checked. Overall, the row count = point_id_0 + mid_points + last_point_n. point_id_0 and last_point_n have unique id, however, mid_points might have multiple id, as can be seen in df1 (e.g., 10195 has 4 lon/lat, 557 has 3...). This makes things more difficult as we need to match mid_points from df2 with id from df1.

Looks like this is doing the work for mid_points: json_coordinates <- field_TO_pro_simplify %>% select(mid_points ) json_coordinates <- toJSON(json_coordinates)
Parse the JSON string
parsed_json <- fromJSON(json_coordinates)
Extract the coordinates
coordinates_list <- lapply(parsed_json$mid_points , function(x) {   fromJSON(x) })
Flatten the list of coordinates and convert to a data frame
coordinates_df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(coordinates_list, function(x) {   data.frame(Coordinates = paste0("[", x[,1], ", ", x[,2], "]")) }))

This is a partial answer to show how one might work with columns containing JSON strings of (nested) lists and with resulting list columns. I'm afraid there's just not enough information available in the question to assign id and point_id values for mid-point coordinates.
Resulting id is a list column, for first and last points of each group id list includes a single value; for all midpoints it holds remaining id values.
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(jsonlite, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
df2 |> 
  # parse JSON columns with parse_json
  mutate(across(c(id, point_id_0:last_point_n), \(x) map(x, parse_json))) |> 
  # combine point_id_0, mid_points & last_point_n into a single column, rowwise
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(pts = c(list(point_id_0), mid_points, list(last_point_n)) |> list(),
         .keep = "unused", .after = country) |>
  ungroup() |> 
  # unnest newly create pts column, hoist lon & lat to top-level columns
  unnest_longer(pts) |> 
  hoist(pts, lon = 2, lat = 1) |> 
  select(-pts) |> 
  # group by id, assign 1st and last id-s, for mid-points leave a list of id candidates
  mutate( 
    id = case_when(row_number() == 1   ~ list(first(id[[1]])), 
                   row_number() == n() ~ list(last (id[[1]])),
                   .default = id[[1]] |> head(-1) |> tail(-1) |> list()) ,  
    .by = id) |> 
  # display list column content and increase number of displayed digits 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(id_chr = paste0(id, collapse = ","), .after = id, across(lon:lat, \(x) tibble::num(x, digits = 9) )) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  print(n = 28)

Result:
#> # A tibble: 28 × 7
#>    id         id_chr         country           lon          lat route_id value_B
#>    <list>     <chr>          <chr>       <num:.9!>    <num:.9!>    <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 <int [1]>  10195          United… -98.467885430 35.315145480      883   3501.
#>  2 <list [4]> 557,10123,101… United… -98.528388210 35.335141830      883   3501.
#>  3 <list [4]> 557,10123,101… United… -98.610076200 35.341343820      883   3501.
#>  4 <list [4]> 557,10123,101… United… -98.681028730 35.322564430      883   3501.
#>  5 <list [4]> 557,10123,101… United… -98.740603430 35.314511000      883   3501.
#>  6 <list [4]> 557,10123,101… United… -98.796368000 35.298251000      883   3501.
#>  7 <list [4]> 557,10123,101… United… -98.879140440 35.309144560      883   3501.
#>  8 <list [4]> 557,10123,101… United… -98.975973410 35.404679710      883   3501.
#>  9 <list [4]> 557,10123,101… United… -98.980236830 35.504573670      883   3501.
#> 10 <int [1]>  10083          United… -98.980236833 35.504573666      883   3501.
#> 11 <int [1]>  5349           United… -80.786228740 40.759502800      884  20912.
#> 12 <list [2]> 5369,5414      United… -80.757632000 40.803904000      884  20912.
#> 13 <list [2]> 5369,5414      United… -80.761536000 40.835328000      884  20912.
#> 14 <list [2]> 5369,5414      United… -80.728872000 40.832602000      884  20912.
#> 15 <list [2]> 5369,5414      United… -80.628096000 40.824192000      884  20912.
#> 16 <list [2]> 5369,5414      United… -80.588928000 40.844928000      884  20912.
#> 17 <list [2]> 5369,5414      United… -80.519680000 40.870912000      884  20912.
#> 18 <list [2]> 5369,5414      United… -80.441874000 40.887313000      884  20912.
#> 19 <list [2]> 5369,5414      United… -80.325376000 40.911872000      884  20912.
#> 20 <list [2]> 5369,5414      United… -80.146112000 40.935712000      884  20912.
#> 21 <int [1]>  5455           United… -79.992576000 40.926591999      884  20912.
#> 22 <int [1]>  13184          United… -99.184257140 26.801970700      885   1795.
#> 23 <list [2]> 13217,13235    United… -99.161901540 26.770835690      885   1795.
#> 24 <list [2]> 13217,13235    United… -99.091625500 26.860638500      885   1795.
#> 25 <list [2]> 13217,13235    United… -99.047338330 26.992620000      885   1795.
#> 26 <list [2]> 13217,13235    United… -99.011691500 27.043023670      885   1795.
#> 27 <list [2]> 13217,13235    United… -98.943566480 27.246088450      885   1795.
#> 28 <int [1]>  13251          United… -98.943566477 27.246088455      885   1795.

Input frame:
df2 <- structure(list(id = c("[10195, 557, 10123, 10105, 10088, 10083]", 
"[5349, 5369, 5414, 5455]", "[13184, 13217, 13235, 13251]"), 
    country = c("United States", "United States", "United States"
    ), point_id_0 = c("[35.31514548, -98.46788543]", "[40.7595028, -80.78622874]", 
    "[26.8019707, -99.18425714]"), mid_points = c("[[35.33514183, -98.52838821], [35.34134382, -98.6100762], [35.32256443, -98.68102873], [35.314511, -98.74060343], [35.298251, -98.796368], [35.30914456, -98.87914044], [35.40467971, -98.97597341], [35.50457367, -98.98023683]]", 
    "[[40.803904, -80.757632], [40.835328, -80.761536], [40.832602, -80.728872], [40.824192, -80.628096], [40.844928, -80.588928], [40.870912, -80.51968], [40.887313, -80.441874], [40.911872, -80.325376], [40.935712, -80.146112]]", 
    "[[26.77083569, -99.16190154], [26.8606385, -99.0916255], [26.99262, -99.04733833], [27.04302367, -99.0116915], [27.24608845, -98.94356648]]"
    ), last_point_n = c("[35.50457366645043, -98.98023683317503]", 
    "[40.9265919994913, -79.9925760003392]", "[27.24608845465542, -98.94356647741596]"
    ), route_id = c(883, 884, 885), value_B = c(3500.69, 20911.7359999998, 
    1794.77)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

df2
#> # A tibble: 3 × 7
#>   id                 country point_id_0 mid_points last_point_n route_id value_B
#>   <chr>              <chr>   <chr>      <chr>      <chr>           <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 [10195, 557, 1012… United… [35.31514… [[35.3351… [35.5045736…      883   3501.
#> 2 [5349, 5369, 5414… United… [40.75950… [[40.8039… [40.9265919…      884  20912.
#> 3 [13184, 13217, 13… United… [26.80197… [[26.7708… [27.2460884…      885   1795.
glimpse(df2)
#> Rows: 3
#> Columns: 7
#> $ id           <chr> "[10195, 557, 10123, 10105, 10088, 10083]", "[5349, 5369,…
#> $ country      <chr> "United States", "United States", "United States"
#> $ point_id_0   <chr> "[35.31514548, -98.46788543]", "[40.7595028, -80.78622874…
#> $ mid_points   <chr> "[[35.33514183, -98.52838821], [35.34134382, -98.6100762]…
#> $ last_point_n <chr> "[35.50457366645043, -98.98023683317503]", "[40.926591999…
#> $ route_id     <dbl> 883, 884, 885
#> $ value_B      <dbl> 3500.69, 20911.74, 1794.77

Also note that all 28 coordinate pairs in provided (dput) sample are unique, and there are signs of precision issues. For example consider rows 9 & 10 of resulting frame, corresponding values in input data are:
35.50457367,       -98.98023683
35.50457366645043, -98.98023683317503

